# SQL Query - How to find the neighbour country with highest elevation point

Tags: sql, postgresql

I just started learning SQL. I am stuck on this problem. It would be appreciated if you could help me on this.

**Question:**

> For each country, find its neighbor country with the highest elevation point. Report the `id` and `name` of the country and the `id` and `name` of its neighboring country.

Output Table: **query1**

The schemas are:

country   (cid, cname, height, population);

```
CREATE TABLE country (
    cid         INTEGER     PRIMARY KEY,
    cname       VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    height      INTEGER     NOT NULL,
    population  INTEGER     NOT NULL);
```

neighbour (country, neighbor, length);

```
CREATE TABLE neighbour (
    country     INTEGER     REFERENCES country(cid) ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    neighbor    INTEGER     REFERENCES country(cid) ON DELETE RESTRICT, 
    length      INTEGER     NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(country, neighbor)
);
```

Attributes:

```
c1id   (country id)            [INTEGER]
c1name (country name)          [VARCHAR(20)]
c2id   (neighbor country id)   [INTEGER]
c2name (neighbor country name) [VARCHAR(20)]
```

Order by:

```
c1name   ASC
```

Comment: You need to write a SELECT statement that retrieves the output you want.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical use case for `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
        c1.cid, c1.name, c2.cid neighbour_cid, c2.name neighbour_name,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c1.cid ORDER BY c2.height DESC) rn
    FROM 
        country c1
        INNER JOIN neighbour n ON n.country  = c1.cid
        INNER JOIN country c2  ON n.neighbor = c2.cid
) x WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY name, neighbour_name
```

The inner query uses two `JOIN`s to bring all the neighbours of each country. `ROW_NUMBER()` assigns a rank to each neighbour, order by decreasing height. You can run the inner query independantly to see the results it produces.

Then, the outer query just filters in the record ranked first in each group (in other words, for each country, the neighbour with the greatest height).